# Slow OSX booting with black screen before apple logo

Tags: macos, startup

Every time I boot my macbook, there is always a black screen before the Apple Logo pops up. The blackscreen stays for around 15-20 seconds. How can I resolve that problem?

Comment: Which OS X version are you talking about ??

Answer (score 3):

It can happen, if you doesn't have selected a specific start-volume.

1. From the Apple menu choose System Preferences.
2. Click the Startup Disk icon in System Preferences, or choose View > Startup Disk.
3. Select your startup disk from the list of available volumes.

After that, restart your mac and the blackscreen shouldn't appear before a start.

Comment: Starting with OS X Yosemite, this black screen will appear for a longer time then before (but not for 15-20 sec.) - why I don't know - but it does. And I have only one Startup disk which is default selected in System Preferences.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. New to OS X and just bought a macbook pro. No idea why this wasn't on by default. The pause was so long at times I thought my macbook had died already.